# Google Apps Scripts: Logger does not print

Tags: logging

Currently, if I select and run the function it does not print

"Test".

```
function NextMonth() {
    //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('You clicked the 
NextMonth menu item!');
    Logger.log('Test');
//NextMonthLib.NextMonth();
```

### }

### Execution started
Execution completed

A while ago, if I selected and ran the function, it would execute and would print "Test".

How can I enable the logger to print information?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're referring to browser console or execution log but both `logger.log()` and `console.log()` work.

All logs are available in the "executions" panel of the Apps Script development interface, just open the execution that you need to examine.

If you're testing code directly in the Apps Scripts interface, you can also just click the Execution Log button in the menu above your code to view your code's outputs when they run.

Cheers

Comment: I'm referring to the execution log.  I still can't get Logger.log to output anything.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done is, as you've said, click the Execution Log button, and in the window the my `Logger.log` message does not appear.